# How to limit the number of users connecting to the server computer vnc?

Tags: vnc

If two devices or more connect to same ip address, they are connected to the ip address at the same time. I want to limit user number so that only one user at a time may connect to the server computer. Is it possible? If it is, what should I do?

Comment: I think you are thinking about this the wrong way.  You mean only one user may connect to VNC at a time? right?  Not "connected to the ip address".. right?  I just googled "vnc limit connections" and found so much information.. your solution will depend of what VNC you are using (and what operating system).  Two pieces of information that you did not provide.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thank you for the comment. I noticed that I didn't provide enough information. I think I may find out the solution by your comment. Thank you.

Comment: depends on which VNC server / client software is in use.